# what to do for dynamically changing xpaths in python using selenium?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I have a `xpath` as:

```
//*[@id="jobs-search-box-keyword-id-ember968"]
```

The number 968 constantly keeps on changing after every reload.
Rest of the string remains constant.

How to I find the constantly changing `xpath`?

Comment: This _xpath_ `//*[@id="jobs-search-box-keyword-id-ember968"]` will locate a particular element within the HTML where the part of the text **968** will be assigned dynamically. Hence you need to locate the  element with reference to the _ancestor_ node. So you need to update the question with more of the _outerHTML_.

Comment: Please update your question with some HTML code snippet So someone can help you out in better way.

Answer (score 1):

You can use partial `id` with `contains()`

```
//*[contains(@id, "jobs-search-box-keyword-id-ember")]
```

Comment: It is again giving me the same error: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[contains(@id, "jobs-search-box-keyword-id-ember")]"}

Comment: @FarhaanPatel Try adding some [wait](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#explicit-waits)

Comment: I did, but same results.

Comment: @FarhaanPatel Is this inside `<iframe>` tag?

Comment: This is the complete xpath:  //*[@id="jobs-search-box-keyword-id-ember1365"]

Comment: @FarhaanPatel The `xpath` in my answer should find this element. There are 3 options: 1- timing issue and you need to wait for the element to load, 2- the element is inside `<iframe>` and you need to switch to it, 3- the element doesn't exists.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `starts-with` below,

```
//*[starts-with(@id,'jobs-search-box-keyword-id-ember')]
```

Comment: I tried this as well. My code was: driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[starts-with(@id,'jobs-search-box-keyword-id-ember')]")   and the error was:  no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[starts-with(@id,'jobs-search-box-keyword-id-ember')]"}

Comment: This seems to be a timing issue where you're trying to locate the Element on the Page before its loaded!

Answer (score 0):

The details provided is insufficient to to provide the accurate result. Still you can follow the below code references

In `//*[@id="jobs-search-box-keyword-id-ember968"]` the last number **968** keeps changing. but if you make this like `//*[starts-with(@id,'jobs-search-box-keyword-id-ember')]` then there might be possibility that you can have more then one element with the same partial is i.e. `jobs-search-box-keyword-id-ember` in this case it will locate on 1st matching element. that may not be your expected one

1. Use the tag name lets say element is an input tag whose id is `jobs-search-box-keyword-id-ember968`

   Xpath - `//input[starts-with(@id,'jobs-search-box-keyword-id-ember')]`

   CSS  -  `input[id^='jobs-search-box-keyword-id-ember']`
2. Use the relevant parent element to make this more specific. e.g the element is in parent tag `<div class="container">`

   Xpath- `//div[@class='container']//input[starts-with(@id,'jobs-search-box-keyword-id-ember')]`

   CSS -  `div.container input[id^='jobs-search-box-keyword-id-ember']`

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:
Locator:
JOBS_SEARCH_BOX_XPATH = "//*[contains(@id,'jobs-search-box-keyword-id-ember')]"

Code:
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, JOBS_SEARCH_BOX_XPATH)))
.send_keys("SDET")

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).